# I'm having trouble with the shell in Visual Code Studio in WSL

Tags: bash, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I'm a Visual Code Studio user. I have used the CMD default shell in Visual Studio Code but I passed on ubuntu a few days ago. So I also change the Visual Studio Code default shell by replacing it with ubuntu(wsl). The problem is that when I try to run my script it writes :`-bash: C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe: No such file or directory`.
By the way I'm a Python language user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need WSL to access a bash shell in Visual Studio Code. The most normal way to do it is to install the git-bash app and Visual Studio Code in Windows and then you can access all your installed Python files in Windows from Visual Studio Code and use a bash shell in Visual Studio Code in Windows too.

**Start git-bash** Visual Studio Code extension adds two "bash" commands to VSCode that allow you to start git-bash, either in the folder of the current file or in the workspace's root folder. Open your preferred browser and visit Git Bash downloads page by clicking the following link: [Git Download Page](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Once the page loads, click the **Download for Windows** button.

Plugin provides two commands:

- `bash` will open bash in your current file's directory.
- `bash in workspace` will open bash always in the root workspace directory, despite what file is opened.

Just press F1 and then type any of above commands to start git-bash.exe.

Note that you will need to have git-bash.exe on the environment path.

Comment: Thanks so much it's working !

Comment: @Phonki If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.@Phonki